# jquery ajax send string to php and special charactere such as #

Tags: php, jquery

I am beginning with Jquery and so I am trying to do something very simple : get a string from an input tag and put it into a div tag.

My Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recherche").keyup(function(){
    var recherche = $(this).val();
    var data = 'motclef=' + recherche;
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "result.php",
            data : data,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(server_response){
            $("#resultat").html(server_response).show();
    }
    });
```

});

});

My php code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['motclef'])){
    $motclef = $_GET['motclef'];
    echo $motclef;
}
?>
```

It works fine even for caracters such as éàç... or even chinese caracters but it doesn't work with # or &. How can I make it works ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: try to change the contentType or remove it

Comment: I have tried but same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recherche").keyup(function(){
    var recherche = $(this).val();
    var data = 'motclef=' + recherche;
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "result.php",
            data : {motclef: data},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(server_response){
            $("#resultat").html(server_response).show();
    }
    });
```

Comment: "data : {motclef: data}," jQuery will encode and produce and nice query string as you would have done by writing page.php?motclef=contenudetoninputencode

Comment: De rien ! PS: you don't need to specify the contentType, I think this is the jQuery default value (ça rendra ton code plus facile à lire ;) )

Comment: ok merci du conseil je vais l'effacer. Encore merci et bonne continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're sending your data using GET, you need to URL encode your data before sending it with Ajax. Use the javascript function 'escape'

```
escape('&# '); // "%26%23%20"
```

Comment: ok thanks, I have changed the line data : data, by data : escape(data), but now nothing appears on the div tag

Comment: Was it send successfully to PHP? Also you should try to unescape your data (server_response) before adding it as HTML.